# Dynamic string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have to read from a file and print the output in the form of a table using string formatting
Here is an example of what i wrote

```
def timesplit(m,n):
    count=0
    for i in m:
        if i>=n:
            count+=1
    return count
f=open("/home/chandra.pradyumna/logs.properties")
line=f.readlines()
if line[1][-2]=='1':
    k=line[3][line[3].find("=")+1:-1].split(",")
    l=line[4][line[4].find("=")+1:-1].split(",")
print k,l
print "%9s|"*len(k)+"%9s"*len(l)%timesplit(k[0],Exec),timesplit(k[1],Exec),timesplit(k[2],Exec),timesplit(k[3],Exec),timesplit(l[0],Update),timesplit(l[1],Update),timesplit(l[2],Update),timesplit(l[3],Update)
```

Exec and Update are lists containing floats in range(0,50)

The file I am reading is as follows

```
#Enable timesplts=1 else=0
timesplits = 1
#The specific time splits
Exectimespilt=10,15,20,30
Updatetimesplit=10,15,20,30
```

The output should be in a tabular format

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 hour  |exec(>10)|exec(>15)|exec(>20)|exec(>30)|update(>10)|update(>15)|update(>20)|update(>30)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hour-1 |3        |5        |7        |4       |5           |2          |  3        |5        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hour-2 |2         |3        |4        |5       |1           |2          |5
```

The data is filled in the table using timesplit().

So how do i perform the string formatting here dynamically depending on the no of elements in k and l.This is a sample and the table has many other components apart from these two
Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for?  Could you give an example of correct output for this input?

Comment: `timesplits = lambda m, n: sum(i >= n for i in m)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would format every entry separately and then join them together:

```
print ",".join("%9s" % timesplit(i, ...) for i in k), "|", ",".join("%9s" % timesplit(i, ...) for i in l)
```

if this is what you mean.

Please note that your function is named `timesplits()` while you call `timesplit()`.

I also don't know what your 2nd argument (`Exec` resp. `Update`) is supposed to be in this context and how it matches to parameter `n` in the function.

Comment: Well actually this is a part of a code around 1200 lines so i could not give all the values involved.Anyways thanks for your help i solved it.